# Can we use tag to specify preload options in Gorm v2

Tags: go, go-gorm

In `Gorm` version 1 we could tell `Gorm` not to preload nested model by default using struct tag:

```
type NestedModel struct {
}

type Model struct {
    Inner []NestedModel `gorm:"PRELOAD:false"`
}
```

Is there a way to do that with `Gorm` version 2? I would like not to hard-code the specific name of the field in database access service.